Using React hook & state to share data between components is not working as expected
Ok, I am misunderstanding something seriously.
Here is reproduce link
Basically, when a button is clicked from Child component, it should be reflected on the parent component which is App. And I thought using react hook with state would be a good idea.
This is my hook:
import { useState } from 'react';
const useMyHook = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  const change = (param) => {
    console.log(1, 'param in change fn:', param);
    setTest(param);
  };

  return {
    test,
    change,
  };
};

export default useMyHook;

This a parent component
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
import useMyHook from './myHook';

export default function App() {
  const { test } = useMyHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2, 'in APP level, test is:', test);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* expect 'test' to be reflected */}
      <p>test: {test.toString()}</p>

      <Child />
    </>
  );
}


and Child
import React from 'react';
import useMyHook from './myHook';

export default function Child() {
  const { test, change } = useMyHook();
  return (
    <>
      <p>I am child</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          change(!test);
        }}
      >
        click to change
      </button>
    </>
  );
}


I put console.log in useMyHook and App's useEffect.
Whenever I click a button, useEffect never get executed.
I don't even think I need the useEffect but just thought <p>test: {test.toString()}</p> would be working because when state is changed, React will re-render.
What's the best way to share data between components?
(1. I don't want props-drilling)
(2. I think using context is too much since I just want to share a boolean)
(3. Using react-query would be ideal?)
Edit

I realised useMyHook() creates a new one so the one in the one in App.js and the other one in Child.js are different and not connected at all!

in my real-life situation, there are multiple nested components between App and Child. So I bet prop-drilling is a bad solution.

I ended up using react-query rather than Context since I am already using the react-query. What I heard that is whenever Context state changes, any components that are using the Context will re-render. I wonder if it's the same case for react-query. If it's the case, should I use things like Zustand or Jotai?



Why not just use a simple callback, thus when the button is clicked a state in App.tsx will be updated?

One way to do it is props. Should not be called props drilling for just one level. Another way to do it is context, if there are far too many levels.

But the hook you have made is invoked two times, and they are completely separate invocations. Think of it like this, if you use the Child component twice in your JSX, would they be aware of each other or would they be able to communicate? No right, unless you have some global state around it. That global state is context. But as i said, using a callback like prop is just good enough in this case

You're essentially using the hook like a context, except without the context functionality. Either pass down the props from the parent, or convert its implementation and usage to a Context. Note that passing down the props doesn't mean you have to name them exactly the same, or even pass them in separately. Instead, make Child take an onButtonClick prop, and in your App create a useCallback handler that you pass in as that prop. Aim for clean interfaces, extend existing patterns for exposing events, and keep clear delineation of responsibility for each part of your code.

@Petros: it's because the button is located in Child component.

@TusharShahi: in my real problem, I have multiple nested layers (and loops) so prop-drilling is not a ideal solution. Maybe I have to go with Context but I feel that it's kinda overkill

Do not use react-query for this, you should only use it for async state management and this does not look like a use case for it.
You are treating that custom hook as a singleton when in reality each time you call useMyHook you are creating a new independent instance, in order to solve that you need to make sure that useMyHook retrieves the same getter and the same setter across all instances. In order to do so you will need to wrap the components in a context, so all uses of useMyHook pull the values from the context instead of registering new state.
Check this stackblitz I made for you, since you're saying it's just a boolean I used a dark/light theme switch example.
Zustand is also great for use cases like this, if you look at my code in the stackblitz, you can only use useMyHook with components that were previously wrapped in the ThemeContext if you don't want to worry about this you can use Zustand and forget about wrapping things in providers.
When to use Providers vs Zustand?
If you have a component that has multiple instances like a Card that has a lot of nested components like CardDeleteButton CardDeleteConfirmationModal, CardArchiveButton, CardArchiveConfirmation, and many things like those that would need to share state and it's not "Global" but "per card" you could wrap each card in a ContextProvider and these child components will pull the state from the context.
If you need a real singleton, use Zustand (or Jotai). You will pull the same information across all components every time. It's great for things that stay true throughout the whole app, like isDarkMode, isNotificationPanelOpen, and things like that.
Hope that helps

you should use context with react query, that will solve your problem
below url will help you to implement
https://medium.com/@olivier.trinh/react-query-and-react-context-869fedfd0729 (React)
https://krishanmadushankadev.medium.com/using-context-api-with-react-query-tanstack-query-react-native-480c4d6d44cb (React Native)

There is no need to do that, you can pull data straight from the query cache and forget about wrapping things in context, that kinda defeats the purpose of using react-query, react-query shines as a state management, and doesn't need to be integrated with context
